# greensock animation not executing properly after first run

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

Good afternoon, 
I am working on a banner with a greensock animation. For conciseness I have removed everything, leaving only a bouncing ball. On complete, the animation repeats itself as many times as specified in a defined variable ("loop"). The first time everything works fine, the problem comes on the second (and third and so on) repeats - one of the tweens (the second one) is not executing properly, more precisely, its "top" property is not executing. If I remove the position parameter on the following third tween, everything works fine but I obviously want it with it :).
Thanks a lot!
Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
            <img id="ball" src="ball.png"/>
        </div>

        <style>
#banner{
    height: 600px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: black;
}
#ball{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: -50px;
    left: 60px;
}
        </style>
        <script>
        var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var loop = 2;
var tween1 = new TimelineLite({onComplete: onAnimationComplete});
    tween1.to(ball, 0.1, {top: 100, left: 0})
    .to(ball, 0.3, {top: 480, left: 52})
    .to(ball, 0.3, {top: 160, rotation: 360}, '-=0.1')
    .to(ball, 0.1, {top: 160})
    .to(ball, 0.2, {top: 420})
    .to(ball, 0.1, {left: -60, top: 530});

function onAnimationComplete() {

            if (loop > 0) {
                loop -= 1;
            }

            if (loop !== 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tween1.pause().progress(0);
                }, 2000);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    tween1.restart();
                }, 4000);
            }
        }</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may have something to do with  the  '-=0.1'  value passed to the 3rd to in the tween.

Comment: For ease of testing,  I created a plunkr of your code (with different background color and ball for conveience)  here: https://plnkr.co/edit/wM78M14dvHDotCWUPksk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks man! The problem is that without the position parameter ("-=0.1") the animation works fine, but with it the effect of a bouncing ball looks much better and this is why I want it inside the timeline. Actually after five days spent on it I don't want it anymore, it just gets me mad that I can't solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reset all your values to the default ones at the beginning of the timeline with something like.

```
tween1.set(ball, {top:-50, left:60});
```

also you might wanna animate x and y instead of top and left since it will be more performant by animating tranforms.